# NULL constraint violated in sql insert

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (Location) shown below.  When I try to insert items, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "loc_id" violates not-null constraint
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into Location VALUES ( lng , lat , alt ) RETURNING loc_id"

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Location ( 
     longitude double precision check( longitude IS NULL OR -180.0 < longitude AND longitude <= 180.0 ),
     latitude double precision check( latitude IS NULL OR -90.0 <= latitude AND latitude <= 90.0 ),
     altitude double precision  default(0), 
     unique(longitude,latitude,altitude),
     loc_id integer  DEFAULT nextval('loc_seq') 
);
```

Comment: That fixed it, but why was there a problem to start?

Comment: Yeah, actually it worked for me. I just created the sequence `loc_seq` with `CREATE SEQUENCE loc_seq`, then did the `CREATE TABLE` and finally  
`insert into Location VALUES ( 0,0,0 ) RETURNING loc_id`. I don't know if it's your PostgreSQL version or something...

Comment: I have had the same experience.  It will work, I will modify some other table definition and it will stop working.  Hoping the new approach of 'serial primary key' fixes it for good.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I couldn't reproduce the error, it worked in my environment (PostgreSQL 9.0). But if you come across this error, I would still recommend to try the following:

If you don't supply values to all the columns in the table define in the `INSERT` clause the columns you are inserting the values to:

```
insert into Location (longitude, latitude, altitude) VALUES ( lng , lat , alt ) RETURNING loc_id
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly add the next value in the sequence with `nextval`.

```
insert into Location VALUES ( lng , lat , alt, nextval('loc_seq')) RETURNING loc_id
```

Comment: I thought you could just leave out columns at the end?

Comment: @LenB i never tried leaving out columns. you could write ... `VALUES ( lng , lat , alt, default)`